# Relation between an subspace $W$ and $int\, W$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let be $W\subset R^n$ a subspace, 
I want to prove that $W$ is closed.

and a friend tells me that it comes from  $int(W)=\emptyset$, I know how to show that if $W$ is a subspace then $int(W)=\emptyset$ but is not clear for me why this implies that $W$ must to be closed.

Comment: Note that the interior of $\Bbb Q$ is $\emptyset$

Comment: If $W$ is a subspace (as in linear) then it is always closed (in finite dimensions).

Comment: @copper.hat why?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/37849/closedness-of-finite-dimensional-subspaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

False. Take $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$ for a counterexample. $\mathbb{Q}$ is not closed, since $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}=\mathbb{R}$ but the fact that between every two rational numbers one can find an irrational number shows that $\mathbb{Q}$ is neither open (doesn't contain any open ball about any of its points)